# Kinect - 2 features simultaneously

Tags: kinect, directshow, directshow.net, kinect-sdk

I am trying to extract 2 features from the Kinect :

1. **Captured video** - I followed this guide:
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdk/thread/4ee6e7ca-123d-4838-82b6-e5816bf6529c
   and succeeded to use the kinect as webcam and then used DirectShow in order to capture the video. Works just fine.
2. **skeleton** - I use the 1.7 Kinect SDK and the skeleton feature works sweet!

**The Problem:** *Those 2 features don't work simultaneously*
Each one of them works great by itself, but they just don't work together.
I have also tried checking the captured video in Skype's video settings section, while running the Skeleton Basics in the "Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit 1.7"

Do you know why that happens and how can I fix that problem and enjoy the 2 features simultaneously?

Thanks a lot,
Guy.

Comment: Define "don't" work together" please? What language are you using and listening to what events? Should work together..

Comment: "Capture Video" is not a feature, it is a unsupported hook that is likely disabling at least part of the default driver behavior -- which is why the `Skeleton` tracker isn't functioning.  The [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) supports recording of the different streams and may do what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

this cannot be happen. I'm also working on a virtual dressing room concept and I could access the kinect joints and also the video stream too. I'm using xna so its cool with me to get the video buffer to the `kinectSensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
                kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable(new TransformSmoothParameters()`
I don't know what's your approach